# FacebookOAuthException when using the Facebook C# API

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the Facebook C# API in a Desktop application and retrieve an access token via OAuth in an embedded browser. The access token works fine when I use it in the Graph API Explorer. However, when I do a call from C# using the SDK, I get a FacebookOAuthException. The message is: "(OAuthException - #2500) Unknown path components: /me".

```
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken); // token confirmed to work via API Explorer
client.Version = "2.11";
client.AppId = appid;
dynamic me = client.Get("me");
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version needs to be specified as "v2.11", not "2.11".